# Problem getting new data from SQL in python every few seconds

Tags: python, sql

My team and i want to make a python script that consistently checks the Mysql database and prints out new updated records every few seconds. However, i keep getting errors saying nothing in database where there is. 
Any idea why?

```
import time
sql_conn = connectSQLServer('ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS', 'display')
mycursor = sql_conn.cursor()
global prev_id
a = 0
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        a=a+1
        print(a)
        prev_id = x[0]
        sql = "SELECT ID, val FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer WHERE id > %s"
        mycursor.execute(sql, prev_id)   

        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            print(x)
            prev_id = x[0]
    except Exception as error:
        print("Nothing in database\n")
        print(error)
sql_conn.commit()
```

Comment: I believe you're missing `".... WHERE id > %s"% (prev_id)` at the end of the query, and just do a `myresult = mycursor.fetchall(sql, prev_id)`, I believe you can skip that `execute()` line

Comment: I have updated the code, but it is still saying nothing in database, any help would be nice.. been struck for quite some time omgg

Comment: what is `id > %s` ? in your query that has to accept some sort of id right, assuming that's the role of `prev_id`?

Comment: yes, it is. i have tried to hardcode like `id > 2000` but nth is showing, guess theres sth wrong with the formatting which i cant solve

Comment: when you execute with the hard-coded `id` value do you still need that `prev_id` when doing the execute, you would only need `.execute(sql)` maybe try that...also why the need for a default schema `dbo` can't you create your own table like `dataStored` ?

Comment: yeap. i want to generate line after line of the new updated data from sql, so i want ID greater than that maximum value from my previous query

Comment: what is the full traceback error saying?

Comment: oh wow! it works now! using  ".... WHERE id > %s"% (prev_id) at the end of the query! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
sql_conn = connectSQLServer('ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS', 'display')
mycursor = sql_conn.cursor()
global prev_id
a = 0
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        a=a+1
        print(a)
        prev_id = x[0]
        sql = "SELECT ID, val FROM dbo.LiveStatsFromSQLServer WHERE id > %s" % prev_id
        mycursor.execute(sql)   
        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            print(x)
            prev_id = x[0]
    except Exception as error:
        print("Nothing in database\n")
        print(error)
sql_conn.commit()
```

Comment: you should explain what you've done to resolve your own issue.

Comment: apparently it is mycursor.execute(sql)  not mycursor.execute(sql,prev_id)

Comment: Welcome to the community. please edit your answer explaining what you have done. this should help other developers facing the same issue.